# compress responses in EJB GZip and Jersey 1.6?

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, ejb

I wish to selectively compress responses for certain apis.

I found this very nice article explaining exactly what i needed :
[gzip compression with jax-2x](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-compress-responses-in-java-rest-api-with-gzip-and-jersey/)

However, my application uses JAX-1.6 (I have worked with Spring, life was easy, until i have to work with EJB-Jersey now).

How can I achieve the same with JAX-1.6?